# How do I capture the Print Event in PrintPreviewDialog

Tags: c#, printing

I am inheriting from the PrintPreviwDialog class in c#. I want to override the Print button on the toolbar, so that I can give the option of printer selection.

Unfortunately it looks like the toolbar control that has the print button is private, and I don't see any events that I can override.

There must be some solution to getting the print preview dialog and then being allowed to use the PrintDialog control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear I just have to recreate all the functionality I want in a new form with the controls. The PrintPreviewDialog class is worthless.

Comment: Agreed! I have had to do the exact same thing recently. Rolling your own is surprising easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PrintDialog first to select a printer then open the PrintPreviewDialog.

Comment: I think it would be confusing for customers to select a printer before previewing.